# How can I set the texts of my html page after a function callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, synchronization, web-sql

I have a function in Web Sql for multilanguage.

I need to set the language after the callback of a query, calling by id.

Example:

```
var lng = function(language){

var testo_query="SELECT id," + language + " FROM lingue;";

comanda.sincro.query(testo_query,function(result){

    result.forEach(function(obj){


        //those values will be go into an array 
        //language[id]=obj[language];

        console.log(obj.id,obj[language]);

    });

});

};
```

Then i'd want to write in HTML:

```
<p><script>language[0]</html></p>
```

and in the js function:

```
'('+language[1]+')'
```

But just after the callback function, otherwise the array will not be created.

Could it be done?

https://jsfiddle.net/tbatnwb4/1/

Comment: what's your function supposed to return? need more details about how/what you're tryin to achieve... question not clear...

Comment: the function only set an array with id and language, and i need to use it to set the html page

Comment: Please give a more detailed example... add an "array" sample of what you return, and a html sample. This would really help... why don't you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is an example. I'm not sure this is what you're asking but the "callback" thing should help... http://jsfiddle.net/nwv38rgc/2/

Comment: you have to use a callback. Declare callback in your function definition, and callback the function result. you should read about callbacks man...

Comment: I already have the callback function, but I need the texts of the entire page are generated after the callback function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93974/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-riparazione-computer-mestre-da).

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery to manipulate the DOM with functions like 'append' or 'prepend' inside the forEach and call something like this for calling the function from a string value:

```
var fn = window[settings.functionName];
if(typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn(language[1]);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you do an example? I just need to get the page vars on the function callback.

Comment: he just wants to get something in db, and return it with callback that fires a function... your answer does not fit what he's asking...